# Using Laravel Queue in Supervisord and HHVM results in a lot of .map files in tmp folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, supervisord, hhvm

I am using Larvel 4.1. After creating a new server according to this site (http://www.tienle.com/2014/04-25/setting-nginx-hhvm-php-percona-laravel-projects.html) everything works a lot faster. I have a 40% speed performance! The only problem I still have is the perf-*.map files. Because the Queue of Laravel is running inside supervisord every 2 sec a perf-*.map file is created with the size of 2MB. You can imagine what happens after a week. Sometimes there is a lot of traffic on the website and the files are growing faster. One time the system broke because of a full hard drive. I hope someone experienced this problem before. I googled a lot but couldn't find the answers. I can provide every config file someone needs to solve this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `/etc/hhvm/php.ini`, add:

```
hhvm.keep_perf_pid_map = 0
hhvm.perf_pid_map = 0
hhvm.perf_data_map = 0
```

This should stop the creation and retention of the files.

Comment: Thanks Simon_W! I tried a lot of stuff but this one works perfect!